# Printing Out Repeated Numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, netbeans

so I'm working on a program that takes two strings. For instance [2,3,4] and [1,4,5] and outprints 1,1,4,4,4,5,5,5,5. I don't really have a working code. So, I'm just looking for tips, not a complete code.

Comment: so please show us what you started with

Comment: Could you please explain a bit what you want? Its unclear the description from input and output.

Comment: _"My bad. Outprints: 1,1,4,4,4,5,5,5,5"_ Can you edit original Question to include the expected result.

Comment: Self-vandalism rolled back. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209436/self-vandalism-what-is-correct-action

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to take in strings, I would take two strings and convert each of them into array as you have written e.g.[2,3,4] and [1,4,5] then concatonate them. Then arrange them in order using simple data structure algorithm. So for example, go through each item in the array and move it to the 0 position if it is the smallest number. Then go to the next position and also try to move the lowest number in the array except the first position to the second position, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, I think there should be a **repeat** function. For example, it can repeat 'a' 3 times.Like `a => [a, a, a]`

```
 function repeat(a, times) {
     if (times === 0) return [];
     return [a].concat(repeat(a, times - 1));
 }
```

Then I using it to finish this question.

```
 function repeatAndConcat(times, arr) {
   return arr.map(function(item, index) {
     return repeat(item, times[index]);
   }).reduce(function(a, b) {
     return a.concat(b);
   });
 }
```

repeatConcat([2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 5]) with return [ 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5 ].

The last **reduce** flat a nested array.

Comment: @WebNeoRaven glad I could help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.entries()`, `for..of` loop, spread element, `Array.prototype.fill()` to create array having `.length` set by value of element at first array, filled with value at second array at same index

```js
let [len, arr, res] = [[2,3,4], [1,4,5], []];

for (let [key, prop] of arr.entries()) res.push(...Array(len[key]).fill(prop));

console.log(res);
```